# How deploy Wazuh agent in Kubernetes (EKS)?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, wazuh

Wazuh server installed on EC2 instance .Now i want the logs of kubernetes using wazuh agent . Is it possible ? How setup this ?

I tried to create a docker then run as daemonset in kubernetes , but pod is running not get any logs in server.